# Плывёт вёрстка сцены

Tags: javafx

есть код который запускается при открытии формы логина и при логауте

```
public static void showLoginScene(){
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(400);
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(300);
    primaryStage.setWidth(400);
    primaryStage.setHeight(300);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new LoginStage(primaryStage),400,300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Собственно проблема в том, что при запуске программы форма отображается по центру как и нужно. Далее сцена меняется на 600*800 и там показывается другая сцена. А при нажатии логаута снова вызывается этот метод. Размер окна меняется на нужные 400*300 но панель логина центрируется так, как будто она всё ещё 800*600. Если потянуть окно для ресайза всё снова перерисовывается корректно. Есть предположение, то установка размера primaryStage не устанавливает размер сразу, и нужен какой-то метод перерисовки. Подскажите как пофиксить.

Comment: Не правильно обозвал класс, там не LoginStage, а loginPane которая расширяет BorderPane и привязка идёт к размерам сцены, передаваемом в конструкторе. prefWidthProperty().bind(stage.WidthProperty); prefHeightProperty().bind(stage.HeightProperty);

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в чём была проблема. При получении панели у меня для неё ставился padding, и это каким-то образом всё ломало. Не очень понимаю почему внутренний отступ портит расположение самой панели, но это так.